# Using StringBuilder for appending HTML tags

Tags: android

Issue with StringBuilder

I have used the table tag in sb.append but it is not showing table can any one help me out of this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<table><tr><td>A</td>  <td>B</td>  <td>C</td> </tr><tr><td>X</td>  <td>Y</td>  <td>Z</td> </tr></table> ");

Spanned mainContent = Html.fromHtml(sb.toString());

Log.d(TAG_ID, ""+mainContent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with `StringBuilder`. `Html.fromHtml` doesn't handle all tags, just certain ones for text formatting. If you want to display complete HTML, use a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: hi can u explain how to use this please

Answer (score 1):

Currently `Html.fromHtml` **doesn't supports  `<table>`** tag..

Supported HTML's tag from `Html.fromHtml` are...

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

If you want to use `<table>` tag then you can use `Android WebView` and then method

```
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

also similar method...

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)
```

Load the given data into the WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL for the content.

Comment: i want to send the appended dATA  to facebook as a string how can i store the webview data in string